# Why am I getting this ifstream error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, fstream, ifstream

`Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'`

---

```
#ifndef MAPPER_H
#define MAPPER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "KeyValue.h"
#include "Parser.h"

using namespace std;
class Mapper
{
public:
    Mapper(ifstream& infile);
    ~Mapper(void);
    void loadTokens();
    void showTokens();
    void map();
    void printMap();
    void printMap(string map_fileName);
private:
    ifstream inFile;  //<-- is where the error is happening
    vector<string> tokens;
    vector<KeyValue> map_output;
    Parser* parser;
};

#endif
```

I've even tried putting `std::ifstream` and it still doesn't work.

When I `#include <fstream>` instead of `#include <iostream>`, I get these errors in `fstream.tcc` and `basic_ios.tcc`:

`'operator=' is a private member of 'std::basic_streambuf<char>'`

And since that's part of the fstream library, obviously something i'm doing is wrong...

Anyone able to help?

Comment: You should have `<fstream>` instead of `<iostream>`  The `operator=` is the real error.  The output window should have the rest of that error message, including the line number where you make a copy of a `Mapper` object.

Comment: You need to show the code that causes the second error.

Answer (score 147):

You're missing

```
#include <fstream>
```

and you probably assign somthing to `inFile` which is not allowed.

Comment: For some reason my question cut out the part where I already imported fstream

Comment: You can edit it. And it would help to provide a minimal example that others can try to compile.

Comment: I think `ifstream` is included in `<iostream>` until I took an arrow in my knee.